# How do I use databricks-cli without manual configuration

Tags: bash, azure, databricks, databricks-cli

I want to use databricks cli:

```
databricks clusters list
```

but this requires a manual step that requires interactive work with the user:

```
databricks configure --token
```

Is there a way to use databricks cli without manual intervention so that you can run it as part of a ci/cd pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following bash script, configured the databricks cli automatically:

```
echo "configuring databrick-cli authentication"

declare DATABRICKS_URL="https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net"
declare DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN="authentication_token_generated_from_databricks_ux"

declare dbconfig=$(<~/.databrickscfg)
if [[ $dbconfig = *"host = "* && $dbconfig = *"token = "* ]]; then
  echo "file [~/.databrickscfg] is already configured"
else
  if [[ -z "$DATABRICKS_URL" || -z "$DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN" ]]; then
    echo "file [~/.databrickscfg] is not configured, but [DATABRICKS_URL],[DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN] env vars are not set"
  else
    echo "populating [~/.databrickscfg]"
    > ~/.databrickscfg
    echo "[DEFAULT]" >> ~/.databrickscfg
    echo "host = $DATABRICKS_URL" >> ~/.databrickscfg
    echo "token = $DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN" >> ~/.databrickscfg
    echo "" >> ~/.databrickscfg
  fi
fi
```

Comment: apparently you can now log on with a username, and password... but on Azure i can never get it to work #voodoo 

Comment: I am trying to run this in R. Do you know how should I go about it using this bash script to run in R?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned above by @usingnamespace, and from [the official docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html#set-up-authentication):

> CLI 0.8.0 and above supports environment variables, an environment variable setting takes precedence over the setting in the configuration file.

```
DATABRICKS_HOST
DATABRICKS_USERNAME
DATABRICKS_PASSWORD
DATABRICKS_TOKEN
```

With that, not only you will **not** be exposing sensitive data in clear text files (*~/.databrickscfg*), you won't need to add any more code to your script.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. It's much better than populating a config file.

Answer (score 5):

You can just export the variables DATABRICKS_HOST and DATABRICKS_TOKEN. With those variables, you don't need a config file.

Answer (score 3):

This is a PowerShell version of the script.

```
write-host Configure databricks access
$Env:DATABRICKS_CONFIG_FILE = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.databrickscfg"
Set-Location $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
Set-Content .databrickscfg "[DEFAULT]"
Add-Content .databrickscfg "host = https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/"
Add-Content .databrickscfg "token = $(db-token)"
```

Comment: To make the configure effective, the databricks-cli commands must be called in the same PS session.